# A function that uses recursion isn't working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


const int maxx = 6;
vector <int> nums {maxx};
string ops = "-----";

bool fillOps (int target, int n=maxx-1) {
    if (n == 0) {
        if (nums[n]==target) {
            cout << target << " GOOD " << endl;
            return true;
        } else {
            cout << target << " GOOD " << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (nums[n] != 0) {
        if (fillOps(target/nums[n], n-1)) {
            ops[n-1]='*';
            return true;
        }
    } else if (fillOps(target*nums[n], n-1)) {
        ops[n-1]='/';
        return true;
    } else if (fillOps(target+nums[n], n-1)) {
        ops[n-1]='-';
        return true;
    } else if (fillOps(target-nums[n], n-1)) {
        ops[n-1]='+';
        return true;
    } else
        return false; 
}

int main() {
    ops=".....";
    for (int i=0; i<maxx; i++)
        cin >> nums[i];
    int target;
    cin >> target;

    if (fillOps(target))
        cout << ops;
    else
        cout << "No solution exists.";
}
```

The user is expected to enter 5 integers and a target number. The program is supposed to return the operations that you have to perform in order to get to the target number.

Example Input:

7 3 100 7 25 9
881

Example Output:

`*+*++`

Another example of input:

100 6 3 75 50 25
952

Output of that:

`+**-/`

Another example of input:

3 8 7 6 3 1
250

Example of output for above example:

`+*+*+`

Note that operations go from left to right for this program, i.e.,

`(((((3+8)*7)+6)*3)+1) = 250`

This is a solution to a challenge that I found on reddit. I want to solve this using recursion. I tried my but it doesn't seem to work properly. I've been banging my head around this problem for a a couple of weeks.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: First, not all return paths return a determinate value.

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Wall` to see some problems.

Comment: I love the title.

Comment: @LogicStuff Oops. I forgot an "else" over there. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that every path has a `return`. Do not calculate in reverse order, this overs complicates the algorithm. See my following code and read the comments:

```
const int maxx = 5;
std::vector <int> nums(maxx); // <-- vector with 5 elements
std::string ops = "-----";

bool fillOps (int target, int current, int n=maxx-1) {

    if (n == 0) {
        // end of recursion path : do no output here becaus it is too early 
        return current == target;
    }

    int i = maxx - n;
    if (nums[i] != 0 &&                           // <-- test divison by zero
        target % nums[n] == 0 &&                  // <-- test division has no rest
        fillOps(target, current/nums[i], n-1) ) { // <-- and fillOps in same condition
        ops[i-1]='/';
        return true;
    } else if (fillOps(target, current*nums[i], n-1)) {
        ops[i-1]='*';
        return true;
    } else if (fillOps(target, current-nums[i], n-1)) {
        ops[i-1]='-';
        return true;
    } else if (fillOps(target, current+nums[i], n-1)) {
        ops[i-1]='+';
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}

int main() {
   ops=".....";
   for (int i=0; i<maxx; i++)
       std::cin >> nums[i];
   int target;
   std::cin >> target;

   if (fillOps(target, nums[0]))
       std::cout << ops;
   else
       std::cout << "No solution exists.";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This work partially though. If you enter 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, you get ///// which is completely wrong. Thanks a lot. I mean it. Really. This is a huge amount of progress. Thanks!

Comment: @Superex I presented a new solution.

Comment: This one is great. I wonder how I did not think of this in this way. I feel so stupid. Hopefully I'll get less stupider over time. Thanks a lot. I love recursion!